# Implicit region misses definitions

Tags: plotting, regions

I'm running the code

```
eq1[v_] := eq1[v] = v[[2]] + Tan[\[Pi]/6] v[[1]];
```

```
In[271]:= Region@ImplicitRegion[eq1[{x, y}] == 4 && 0 < x < 2, {x, y}]

Out[271]= Region[
ImplicitRegion[
And[And[80.61330507707726, 0 < x < 69.81317007977395] == 4, 
   0 < x < 2], {x, y}]]
```

This output is not recognized as a region, while by typing differently, I get the output that I want

```
Region@ImplicitRegion[x/Sqrt[3] + y == 4 && 0 < x < 2, {x, y}]
```

[image]

Why is that??? There is something wrong with how I write the code???

Comment: Name the region `reg=ImplicitRegion[eq1[{x, y}] == 4 && 0 < x < 2, {x, y}]` and display the region separately `Region[reg]`. That's it!

Comment: `And[80.61330507707726, 0 < x < 69.81317007977395]` has no effective meaning, because the first argument is number, not a boolean (T/F) proposition.